# Select column as other column

Tags: mysql

I have the following table named `attributes`:

```
| identifier | attribute | value      |
|------------|-----------|------------|
| 23         | myKey     | myValue    |
| 24         | hisKey    | hisValue   |
| 25         | herKey    | herValue   |
| 23         | otherKey  | otherValue |
```

I would like to make SQL select query which selects the above rows, groups them by their identifier and uses the `attribute` as the key and the `value` as value for the key.

This means that the a table which looks like the above, should turn into the following PHP array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [identifier] => 23
            [myKey] => myValue
            [otherKey] => otherValue
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [identifier] => 24
            [hisKey] => hisValue
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [identifier] => 25
            [herKey] => herValue
        )

)
```

I have tried the following SQL query:

`SELECT attributes.value as atttributes.attribute FROM attributes GROUP BY identifier`

This will give the following error:

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]:
>   Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near '.attribute FROM attributes GROUP BY
>   identifier' at line 1'

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: Why can't you just loop through records and build that array using PHP?

Comment: I have no idea what SQL output you are looking for. Please provide an example.

Comment: I can. That's no problem. I just thought it would be nicer to do it with a SQL query and maybe even give a better performance.

Comment: @RedFilter I am looking to get the rows represented as in the PHP array.

Comment: This looks eerily like "One True Lookup Table" design.  https://www.google.com/search?q=OTLT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is from a typo. Don't specify the table in an alias.

> SELECT attributes.value as  atttributes.attribute FROM attributes GROUP
>   BY identifier

Here's the correction:

```
SELECT attributes.value as attribute FROM attributes GROUP BY identifier
```

However, it won't get you want you want. MySQL will always return results with the same number of columns in each row.

You'll need to implement this in code with a loop. Instead of GROUP BY, use an ORDER BY, and whenever the identifier changes, start another array.

Comment: I did have a typo. However, when the typo is corrected, I will get the same error. Seems like I'll need do this in code :-)

Comment: @SimonBS, Oops, also, don't specify the table name in an alias. :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you cannot do this with SQL in a reasonable fashion.